# ActiveRecord 'no method found' exception on simple one-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is a very basic task, but I can't for the life of me find the cause of the issue.

I am doing a basic to-do lists attached to user accounts. I am using Sorcery to help with the user authentication & creation, which seemingly works fine.

**The Problem Is This:**

When I try to call `@user.list' in any way, I get the following exception (this is copied out of the rails console):

```
@user = User.where(:email => "me@gmail.com")
   => [#<User id: 1, email: "me@gmail.com", crypted_password:  "$2a$10$tiLFyiuLGSB.UXElEdaTGerSv6/TZoLL4nVFdCNsv1AW...", salt:  "e6275124385b0ea157875bba281c7ae9e3a9858e", created_at: "2011-10-02 05:59:02", updated_at:  "2011-10-02 05:59:02", remember_me_token: nil, remember_me_token_expires_at: nil>] 
@user.lists
NoMethodError: undefined method `lists' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f8b6ca89748>
from /Users/<myaccount>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3.1/gems/activerecord-      3.1.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:459:in `method_missing'
from (irb):4
from /Users/<myaccount>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
from /Users/<myaccount>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/<myaccount>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

**My Code/DB Setup**

The setup is simple - I have a `User` model and a `List` model. a `List` `:belongs_to :user`, and a `User` `has_many :lists`. I have added `user_id` to the `lists` table with the following migration:

```
class AddUserIdForeignKeyToLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :lists, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

I have confirmed that the field `user_id` does exist in my table (MySQL).

My `User` model is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :lists

  authenticates_with_sorcery!

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email  
end
```

... and my `List` model looks like this:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

The table design view from MySQL is as follows:

`users`:

[image]

`lists`:
[image]

This sounds to me like there might be a relationship issue, but I can't seem to put this together. Does anyone have any insight? I've never run into any trouble at all like this running Rails 3.0.X on a linux machine, but this is my first foray into Rails 3.1 on OSX, so I'm not sure if maybe I overlooked an underlying change?

Thanks for any guidance

Comment: Rails server caches Activerecord data, have you tried restarting it?

Comment: @ryudice - Yep, restarted server and console with every change - was a oversight in my User.where clause!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
User.where(...)
```

returns a collection of User objects, not a User object.  You need to get a User object.

```
@user = User.where(...).first
```

or, better

```
@user = User.find_by_email("me@gmail.com")
```

Comment: Wow, I knew this would be an obvious answer - many thanks for pointing this out for me, very much appreciated! I'm sure this would have been WAY more apparent if I had added more than 1 User record in the table, haha

Comment: @David Many thanks for sharing, I was searching everywhere to find these attributes after doing a where instead of find_by call